# How to use Varnish to redistribute FMS HDS

Tags: varnish, flash-media-server

We have an FMS Origin server that is outputting HDS(Also RTMP but we don't want to distribute this). We want to put Vanish on another box and have it act as an  intermediary for our CDNs so their edge servers don't hammer our Origin. Documentation is lack

Answer (score 1):

Configure the FMS Origin server as the backend server in the Varnish VCL file. The CDN should then use the Varnish server as the source for the HDS streams.

Comment: Hey Justin, I configured the backend(FMS Origin server) in the VCL and they appear to be communicating but when I attempt to view my HDS stream, I get playback issues. Do I need to configure anything else on the Varnish box to accomplish this?

Comment: If Varnish is configured to simple pass all requests (not in the cache) to your FMS Origin, then entering the varnish IP into your browser should bring up the FMS demo page that shows that the servers is working.